# django: templates how to fill a table of 3 items in a row

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to fill a table with a list of results. But not sure how to tell the template that it's time to close current  and start a new one, after 3 products was already displayed in current tr....

Would be happy if somebody could advice on it. I am running django 1.1.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easiest way is to use the `divisibleby` filter.

```
{% for item in results %}
{% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3 %}<tr>{% endif %}
<td>{{ item }}</td>
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}</tr>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 15):

Even better is to add a `foorloop.last` condition to add `</tr>` at the end of the last row:

```
{% for item in results %}
{% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3 %}<tr>{% endif %}
<td>{{ item }}</td>
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 or forloop.last %}</tr>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Absolutely! I missed this answer at the first look and wondered why my layout broke all of a sudden :-)